# arcpy.Intersect_analysis using Geometry object as input

Tags: arcpy

Is there a way to run arcpy.Intersect_analysis using an arcpy.Geometry object as one of the input datasets?

I've tried different variations of the following, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_feature_class, ["SHAPE@"], "ObjectID = 100") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        geometry = row[0]

intersection = arcpy.Intersect_analysis([geometry,input_feature_class], arcpy.Geometry(), output_type="POINT")[0]
```

Results in:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 289, in Intersect
raise e
 ValueError: DescribeGeometry: Unexpected error
```

I'm already using a feature layer and SelectLayerByAttribute to achieve the same thing.  I'm curious as to why the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Toying around with this function, it appears to only want a list of one kind. So you cannot mix and match a geometry object with a feature class object. However, you can use a list of geometry objects and it will output it.

So to get around this limitation, copy your features into a geometry object. Something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_feature_class, ["SHAPE@"], "ObjectID = 100") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        geometry = row[0]
geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input_feature_class,arcpy.Geometry())[0]
intersection = arcpy.Intersect_analysis([geometry,geometries], arcpy.Geometry(), output_type="POINT")[0]
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this approach is that it won't use the spatial index, so it will be slow when you have more than a handful of features.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I confirm this and I find it very frustrating... Hope it's not the same for other GP tools which works with list of inputs...

Comment: Copy the geometry into an in_memory feature class, then?  `geom_fc = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management([geometry], 'in_memory/geom_fc)'`

Answer (score 0):

Using geometry for intersect, I think not. Intersect crosses over attributes. From your example, it looks like you're trying to do what I'd call a "self intersect" to see where geometries overlap within a feature class? I've found the best way to do that is a GenerateNearTable_analysis using input_feature_class as both the in_features and near_features:

```
    arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(input_feature_class, input_feature_class, output_feature_class, <fill in other settings as desired>)
```

If you specifically want to know what intersects a particular geometry within a feature class, you can use NearTable for that too. To start, you can speed up extraction of the geometry using a list comprehension, and also cut it to one line:

```
    geometry = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_feature_class, "SHAPE@", "ObjectID = 100")][0]
```

Then do the GenerateNearTable_analysis:

```
    arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(input_feature_class, geometry, out_fc, <fill in other settings as desired>)
```